# How to hit a breakpoint in classic ASP script running in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

I am trying to debug a classic ASP application (written in VBScript) using Visual Studio 2015.

The page which is throwing the error is structured as follows :

```
 <% 
 :
 :
 class MyFile
 :
 :
 899 someObj.Open sSQL, connect
 :
 :
 %>
```

The page throws an error at the line above.

```
COM Error Number : -2147217900 (0x80040E14) 
File Name : /includes/MyFile.Class.asp 
Line Number : 899 
Brief Description : Invalid column name 'Column'.
```

But I cannot debug this. I tried the following

- Putting "Stop" before the line -> Does not work. It just does not
  stop !

  - Debug breakpoint is not hit -> Tried running it from within Visual Studio
  - Debug breakpoint is not hit -> Tried running the page separately and attaching the VS debugger to IISExpress.

Any suggestions ? Is inline script debugging (this is not within javascript) supported at all ?

Comment: I have no idea if Visual Studio is capable of debugging server-side VBScript. The usual way to debug classic asp is `Response.Write [suspected culprit]` combined with `Response.End`. You can also use judicious bits of `On Error Resume Next` (suppress errors) and `On Error Goto 0` (turn errors back on).

Comment: Thank you ! That solved the problem for me ..... Not a very efficient way to debug but it does the job.

Comment: @Martha Yes you can debug VBScript server side, but you have to both configure IIS to allow you to do so and tell Visual Studio to attach to the W3P process.

Answer (score 2):

Select your site in the IIS Management tool, Doubleclick "ASP" in the main window. Set "Send Errors To Browser" to True, enable client-side and server-side debugging as well.

If you have Visual Studio installed, and add a "STOP" instruction anywhere in the vbscript code, you should be able to select Visual Studio as the debugger.

[image: IIS Management tool]